# how to map response to request in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

We are sniffing http port using scapy as follows

```
def resp_print(packet):
     return packet.sprintf("{Raw:%Raw.load%}"

sniff(
iface='eth0',
prn=resp_print,
filter="tcp port 8080")
```

we get both request and response payload but we are not able to relate response to corresponding request.

Can you please let me know how to relate response with corresponding request.